# On Wordpress backend how to remove the "ID" from the titles of Page Attributes dropdown?

Tags: php, wordpress, dropdown

attached in the screenshot

[remove ID from titles?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rczDG.jpg)

The idea is on WP backend to remove the ugly ID NUMBER from the titles, and leave only the titles

i try using the filter 'page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args' as described on Wordpress developer resources in functions.php but no luck trying to remove the IDS from the titles on the dropdown. Any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: Please post your question, your expected outcomes and errors, warning you got.